# Open terminal and run scripts after system full loaded

Tags: 12.04

I have an ubuntu server which I need to run a lot of commands after the system loaded, for example, I have to run the following commands:

```
cd /opt/tomcat/bin
./catalina.sh run

cd /.../app
node index.js

cd ../another_app
node start.js
```

And I want terminal window opened for some of the commands, for example, I would like to see the logs of the application.

Is this possible in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: How to create separate terminal window?

Comment: Look at `man gnome-terminal`